# Open most recent file in tcsh

Tags: shell, ls, tcsh

so I'm trying to create an alias that will open the most recent file in a directpry with an application at our studio.

I get the most recent file with:

```
ls -t .ext | head -1
```

That works fine when I just run that line, but if I try either:

```
echo "ls -t .ext | head -1"
app "ls -t .ext | head -1"
```

I get this returned instead of the file opening:

```
ls -t <all the files in the directory> | head -1
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: When you do:
`app ls -t .ext | head -1`
Application understand the "ls -t .ext | head -1" as a command line parameter, not the result of that command. 
You might want to assign result of "ls ...." to a variable then use that variable passing to app.

Comment: well it won't open the file, instead it executes the ls but doesn't send it through the pipe to head.

Comment: well the issue is, echo $LastFile returns: ls -t .ext | head -1 instead of the result
If I put the commands in () it returns:
ls -t file1 file2 file3 | head -1

Comment: you probably can't do this as an alias, but I don't have a tcsh that I can test with. Make it a script and as @twalberg below shows you, use command-substitution (back-tics only in tcsh, I think). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
app `ls -t .ext | head -1`
```

or

```
app $(ls -t .ext | head -1)
```

Either one of those takes the output of `head` and substitutes it into place in the command line.